# VirtualBox - Internet with "Host-only" over PPP

Tags: networking, virtualbox, iptables, nat, ppp

I have a VM that uses Host-only Network. On the Host Machine I have a ppp0 interface through which I have access to the internet (as additional public IP-address). But if you send traffic from ppp0 to vboxnet0, the virtual machine does not have internet access. I tried this to run on Host Machine:

```
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -F
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface vboxnet0 --out-interface ppp0 --source 192.168.56.100 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --in-interface ppp0 --out-interface vboxnet0 --destination 192.168.56.100 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Also I tried to replace "ppp0" to "eth0" and it works fine. How to do it with PPP?

Comment: By the way, VPN-server has IP 10.0.2.1, client has IP 10.0.2.10. Despite I don't have internet access on my VM with ppp0 -> vboxnet0, I can ping 10.0.2.1 on my VM

Comment: Host Only is secured and isolated. Change to NAT or Bridged and it will work.

Comment: @John you mean it's impossible to get access to the internet through Host-Only Network?

Comment: Yes.   Isolation stops traffic. You want a connection so use the proper Network connection type in VBOX

Comment: @John But I managed to get access to the Internet through eth0 -> vboxnet0 (Host-Only interface). But also can't ppp0 -> vboxnet0

Comment: I think what you see is normal and the connection you got is not generalized to a normal connection.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself. I needed to add routes on physical machine:

**/etc/iproutes2/rt_tables:**

```
100 vpn0
```

```
$ ip rule add from 192.168.56.100 table vpn0
```

```
$ ip route add default dev ppp0 via 10.0.2.1 table vpn0
```

Comment: From the research I did (not totally thorough) that may thwart the isolation of the guest machine

Comment: @John I realized it's not the best solution since I don't see real client's IP-address. Okay, I tried NAT, but I have question. How can I configure my NAT Network to use not default Host's interface (eth0), but additional (ppp0)? I don't see such settings in VirtualBox